# Pandas - Interpolate with specified minimum and maximum values for the interpolated value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a .csv that looks like this

```
value,interpolated,what_it_should_be
34,,34
,,25
25,,25
3,,3
,,5
```

The file is read into python as a pandas dataframe. **I want to interpolate the missing data, but the interpolated has to be be between 5-25 (inclusive)**

```
   value  interpolated  what_it_should_be
0   34.0          34.0               34.0
1    NaN          29.5               25.0
2   25.0          25.0               25.0
3    3.0           3.0                3.0
4    NaN           3.0                5.0
```

---

This is what I have so far. What I need help with is limiting the range of the interpolated values.

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)

df['interpolated'] = df['value'].interpolate(method='linear')

print(df)
```

Comment: Can you specify what you need help on? Do you need help writing the interpolation, or do you need help adding a column to the dataframe?

Comment: @user1558604 I forgot to add my code. It's in the question now.

Comment: I'd add a column which equals the interpolated value if between 5 and 25 or set it to 5 or 25 otherwise

Comment: There is not pandas setting for inside the function call `.interpolate()` I can use?

Comment: Easy enough to check on the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html. No, there is nothing in pandas interpolate that sets min or max values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `clip` then `fillna` back

```
df.value.fillna(df.interpolated.clip(lower=5,upper=25))
0    34.0
1    25.0
2    25.0
3     3.0
4     5.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```